# Need help on conditioning value in php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want that I have an error message if that idno has finish to registered in 2015, No need to unique the idno cause I have to redundant because every year that idno can be save or register on the database but the problem is I want to check if he already registered in 2015 or 2016 or 2017.

Here is my code in saving student information:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['save'])){
$stud_id= $_POST['stud_id'];
$idno = $_POST['idno'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename= $_POST['middlename'];
$year= $_POST['year'];
$dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
$progid = $_POST['progid'];
$user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$syear= $_POST['syearid'];
$YearNow=Date('Y');

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student where idno = '$idno'")or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student,school_year where    student.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow")or die(mysql_error());
$count1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1);


 if (don't know what to condition on this part ) {
    echo"idno $idno has already registered in that year";

}
else{

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO student VALUES ('$stud_id','$idno','$dept_id','$progid','$syear','0','$lastname','$firstname','$middlename','$year','$password','$user_type')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "alert('Successfully Added.');\n";
echo "window.location = 'addusers.php';";
echo "</script>";
}

?>
```

I need help to condition please I need help. Thanks

School_year table has(syearid(unique), from_year(2015), to_year(like 2016))

Comment: What a nice collection of SQL INJECTION security failures you have there. Why don't you use prepared statements? Why don't you escape the variables? Why do you copy all of them?

Comment: We don't know the structure of your tables.

Comment: I've already edit my question and it has the database structure

Comment: I'm unclear on your particular requirements but maybe `$count >= 1 || $count1 >= 1`? Also you should close up the injection holes; and update your driver. I'd close the injection hole first; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1. Your `like` also isn't using `%`s so it is basically an `=` and I don't understand why you'd `like` an integer.. (`like $YearNow`)...

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize first your variables before you bind it to your query to prevent some of the [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). You can use [`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
```

Do it for the rest of the passed on data.

And for your `if()` condition, you can do this (*as pointed out already by @chris85*):

```
if($count >= 1 || $count1 >= 1){

  echo "idno $idno has already registered in that year";

}
```

And please refrain from using `mysql_*` API because it is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), and should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: how to do that like this .., $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM student WHERE idno = :idno');

$stmt->execute(array('idno' => $idno));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}??

Comment: I've just solved it and thanks

Comment: Great. Mc Abhel, you are online. Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.