# how can I appear or echo the image in select option?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]

I want that if I click on the select option , the image will appear below , how to do that here's my code:

```
<?php
            include('connection/connect.php');
            $YearNow=Date('Y');
            $dsds=$rowasa['posid'];
            $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student,school_year,partylist where student.idno = candidates.idno AND school_year.syearid = candidates.syearid AND posid =:a  AND candidates.partyid = partylist.partyid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow");

            $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
            $results->execute();
            for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
                <option style="padding: 35px 50px 35px 80px; background:url('admin/savephp/images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>')  no-repeat scroll 5px 7px / 70px  auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" 

                value="<?php echo $rows['candid'] ?>"><?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>,
                    <?php echo $rows['firstname'] ?>
                - <?php 
                        echo $rows['party_name']?></option>
                <?php

            }

        ?>

        </select>
                <input type="button" value="Next" class="next action-button" name="next">
```

Should I need to echo which part help me please

Comment: Use Javascript or any JS library like jQuery. Ajax also, maybe?

Comment: Didn't get anything from http://stackoverflow.com/a/34079840/ I see @LoganWayne *Hm...* and the OP just keeps on asking and asking... but doesn't accept anything.

Comment: I take it the tutorials haven't helped you much, or have you not yet spent a good 3 months yet?

Comment: That is why he looks familiar, @Fred-ii-.. But anyway, OP should read [more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking questions in SO.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `Javascript` (or `jQuery`) and `Ajax`.

I'll assume first that you have a `<div></div>` which stores the selected candidate's image.

```
<div id="selected_candidate_image"></div>
```

You did not also provide the `tag` details of your `select`, so we can just assign an id for it:

```
<select id="president">
```

And when an option is selected from it, this script would run:

```
$(document).on("change", "#president", function(){

  var candidateid = $(this).val(); /* THE SELECTED CANDIDATE */

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
    url: "getimage.php", /* ACTION WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE DATA */
    data: { "candidateid": candidateid }, /* THE DATA TO BE PASSED */
    success: function(result){ /* GET RETURNED DATA FROM getimage.php */
      $("#selected_candidate_image").html(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE STORED INSIDE THE selected_candidate_image DIV */
    }
  });

});
```

As you might notice in the script, we process the data in `getimage.php`. You can do something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM candidates WHERE idno = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["candidateid"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($image); /* GET THE CORRESPINDING IMAGE */
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo '<img src="/system/admin/savephp/images/'.$image.'">'; /* WHAT YOU ECHO IS WHAT WILL BE RETURNED IN YOUR MAIN FILE */
```